# Win XP: If NET SEND is disabled, is there still a way to send messages across network via cmd?

Tags: windows-xp, cmd

I'm working on a project that will popup on a logged in network computer, but hit a stall when I realized that NET SEND isn't enabled on the network. Is there another viable option (assuming regular user privileges on the network)?

Comment: Hmm, probably not. If there were an alternative, I'd imagine whatever motivated a person to disable `NET SEND` would also motivate them to disable the alternative functionality.

Comment: Anyway, you might have more luck asking this type of question on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), as it has more to do with network administration than programming.

Comment: You could write your own program or use another application like [WinMessenger](http://www.winmessenger.com/).

Comment: Would there be a way to write said program without any admin privileges?

Comment: try msg.exe   http://ss64.com/nt/msg.html

Answer (score 0):

Net send doesn't exist anymore since Win XP.
I've done some research recently and this is the alternative I found:

MSG.EXE

usage: msg /server:*servername* *(=all sessions) /time:*timeout* *message*

---

If you get an "error 5" you need to change this registry key on the receiver's computer:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server]
"AllowRemoteRPC"=dword:00000001
```

(I don't know if *AllowRemoteRPC* is also used for other things, so use at own risk)

If you **still** get an "error 5" you need to add the receiver's credentials to the sender's Credential Manager, under "Windows Credentials"

---

This is an easy-to-use batch file I made for the use of MSG.exe

```
@echo off
:server
cls
set /p server=Computer name of receiver:
:delay
cls
set /p time=Message time-out (sec), 0 is none:
:start
echo Enter "exit" to stop. "Delay" to change delay. "Receiver" to change receiver.
set /p message=Enter message: 
if "%message%" == "exit" goto stop
if "%message%" == "delay" goto delay
if "%message%" == "receiver" goto server
cls
msg /server:%server% * /time:%time% %message%
echo Message sent: %message%
goto start
:stop
```

Hope this helps!